# about Game Center's [Finding a Match Programmatically]

Tags: ios, game-center

My project need a online play.

```
    GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease]; 
    request.minPlayers = 2;     
    request.maxPlayers = 2;        

    GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];
    mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;        
    [presentingViewController presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];
```

the above code made a GameCenter view,if i press button named"Play now",it will call "GKMatchDelegate's [- (void)match:(GKMatch *)theMatch player:(NSString *)playerID didChangeState:(GKPlayerConnectionState)state]", its works ok.

but now, i need use "Finding a Match Programmatically", find match directly with out the official view.

```
[[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker]findMatchForRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(GKMatch *hasmatch, NSError *error) {
        if(error)
        {
            NSLog(@"has error match!!!");
        }
        else if(hasmatch)
        {
            NSLog(@"has match!!!");//in test we really find the match.
            [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            self.match = hasmatch;
            self.match.delegate = self;
        }
    }];
```

now the "GKMatchDelegate's [- (void)match:(GKMatch *)theMatch player:(NSString *)playerID didChangeState:(GKPlayerConnectionState)state]" didn't work.

what should i do,to start the online match?

```
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)theMatch player:(NSString *)playerID didChangeState:(GKPlayerConnectionState)state {

if (self.match != theMatch) return;

switch (state) {
    case GKPlayerStateConnected: 
        // handle a new player connection.
        NSLog(@"Player connected!");

        if (!matchStarted && theMatch.expectedPlayerCount == 0) {
            NSLog(@"Ready to start match!");
            [self lookupPlayers];//i start game here
        }

        break; 
    case GKPlayerStateDisconnected:
        // a player just disconnected. 
        NSLog(@"Player disconnected!");
        matchStarted = NO;
        [delegate matchEnded];
        break;
}
```

}

Comment: Is your GKMatches instance delegate set to your controller? I'm seeing just the matchmakerdelegate set to self

Comment: in findMatchForRequest,if the match is found,self.match = hasmatch;
            self.match.delegate = self; so i think the GKMatches delegate is be set.